# Handling Null objects with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, automapper

I am using Automapper for the following but because there is no record in the contacts table for the client, I am getting a *Object reference not set to an instance of an object.* error.

A collection of contacts exist but Contacts.ContactEmails collection is null.

What is the best way of dealing with this?

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Client, ClientGrid>()
..ForMember(to => to.OfficeEmail, opt => opt.MapFrom(from => from.Contacts == null ? "" : from.Contacts.SingleOrDefault().ContactEmails.FirstOrDefault().Email));
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you modify the Contact class to have a get property that will return the first ContactEmail, if available, or null otherwise? Then you could map to that property instead.

Comment: There are several emails against each Conact, besides Its an entity collection.

Comment: Your code only maps the first email anyway, were you intending on mapping others? Also, you can add a property to entity objects because they are partial classes.

Answer (score 1):

I used `.ConvertUsing<MyTypeConverter>()` to solve this problem:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Client, ClientGrid>()
    .ConvertUsing<ClientToClientGridConverter>();


class ClientToClientGridConverter
    : AutoMapper.ITypeConverter<Client, ClientGrid>
{
    public ClientGrid Convert(AutoMapper.ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (context == null || context.IsSourceValueNull) 
        { 
            return null;
        }

        var client = context.SourceValue as Client;

        var clientGrid = new ClientGrid();

        // conversion rules and logic here

        return clientGrid 
    }
}
```